# OpenJPA & MySQL persist wrong encoded characters

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, openjpa

my mysql db has character encoding utf8. In QueryBrowser i can see **special characters** are correct. In appplication using openjpa i can see the same values also correct.
But when I persist object into DB, I have correct values in application but incorrect in DB!
When I restart application that special characters in application are incorrect.(as they are picked from DB)
All is set to UTF-8, java application works well, reading data from DB is correct but **problem is when openjpa stores values in DB, they turn into '?'.**
Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your encoding on the MySql server configuration level (`my.cnf` file), and also on the level of a specific database. Once, I had similar issue when these two options has been set to different values (encodings).